# WPF iGoogle dock style library

Tags: wpf, igoogle

I'm looking for a docking library or resources that discuss building an iGoogle style dock layout. I've played with a few third party controls today that were mentioned in this post([Recommendations on a WPF Docking Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344205/recommendations-on-a-wpf-docking-library)), but it doesn't fit the layout style I'm looking for.

Imagine a portal interface like iGoogle, where you can arrange elements (user controls in my case) and save the layout and state to a database. I've done this very same thing in asp.net using Telerik's ajax dock control and our business wants to port that same style and behavior to our WPF application.

Has anyone done this style of portal docking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Blacklight](http://blacklight.codeplex.com/) project contains a control named Drag Drop Panel that is exactly what you are looking for. It's for WPF and Silverlight also.

You can see a demo here: http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Blacklight is great and was what we are looking for. We used that to implement our own custom solution. I'll post that code here.