# State and status of AvalonDock, options to AvalonDock

Tags: c#, .net, dockpanel, avalondock

I'm working on a WPF interface that could use [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/releases/view/48794), or a similar dockable windows interface. My understanding is that AvalonDock is a pretty good dockable window interface, but I'm a bit worried about the ongoing status of it. Is it honestly active? Many comments on the site discussion and bug tracker mention the developer being too busy, i.e.

> I've decided to shuthdown my blog site (youdev.net) as I'm too busy for now to update it with regularity. Anyway I created a getting started tutorial for AvalonDock (1.3) that can be accessed from here.
>   I'll try to answer any question you may have into the discussion section.

And there are a number of "Is this still active?" questions in the discussion section.

Thus, my question: Is anyone actually using this in production software? What issues are there with it that would be problematic.

Likewise, if anyone has pointers to a decent dockable window library, free or commercial, I'd be interested in taking a look.

Edit: I'm using C# and .NET 4 in VS2010.

Comment: D'oh! Just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344205/recommendations-on-a-wpf-docking-library but the question regarding AvalonDock's status still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much research as I did on AvalonDock before coming here, I still found something afterward, specifically Sofa, which is a wrapper for AvalonDock making it easier to work with. Sofa was last updated less than a month ago, so activity- at least at the moment- seems high.

This, and some of the comments from the [WPF Docking Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344205/recommendations-on-a-wpf-docking-library) question makes me think that AvalonDock might be *just* stable enough, but that Actipro is a good choice if we need support and a commercial project.

I'll mark this as wiki since the "similar to" quotient is really high, but it might still help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article that might be of use to you, it demonstrates one way of integrating AvalonDock into an MVVM application:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239342/AvalonDock-and-MVVM