# A WPF docking library supporting MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dock

I've already seen some questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344205/recommendations-on-a-wpf-docking-library), but the docking library I'd like to use must have an important feature, which was not asked: it must support MVVM.

So, among Telerik, DotNetBar, DevZest, and the other libraries around there (excluding AvalonDock, which I have already tested), is there one you actually use with MVVM?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AvalonDock should work, I know people use it with Caliburn Micro. http://goo.gl/gRVo5

Comment: @Derek Beattie: Nope, AvalonDock is not MVVM-compatible. I ran into a lot of trouble for that and had to extend the component. I'll write a blog post about it asap so as to leave it available for any developer in need

Comment: Yeah, I'd be curious as to what makes it not Mvvm compatible, I've never used it.

Comment: @Mike, i too am facing similar problem. Did you find any library to support MVVM model

Comment: @Chandermani Nope. The project has been on hold for a few monthes. I'm going to have some time to spend on it soon. I'll update the post if I can find a suitable solution

Comment: I wrote an article on using AvalonDock with MVVM:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/239342/AvalonDock-and-MVVM

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Mike try with this:

1. Easy way: Implement [Sofa, An adaptation of AvalonDock for Prism](http://sofawpf.codeplex.com/)
2. Using AvalonDock and implementing a custom region adapter like this:

   ```
   public class ResizingPanelRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<DockingManager>
   {
   public ResizingPanelRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory factory)
       : base(factory)
   {

   }
   protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
   {
       return new AllActiveRegion();
   }

   protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, DockingManager regionTarget)
   {
       region.Views.CollectionChanged += delegate(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       {
           OnViewsCollectionChanged(sender, e, region, regionTarget);
       };
   }

   private void OnViewsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, IRegion region, DockingManager regionTarget)
   {
       if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
       {
           foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
           {
               UIElement view = item as UIElement;
               if (view != null)
               {
                   //Get 
                   ResizingPanel resizingPanel = GetResizingPanel(regionTarget.Content);
                   resizingPanel.Background = Brushes.White;
                   DocumentPane document = GetDocumentPane(resizingPanel.Children);
                   //document.Background = Brushes.White;

                   DocumentContent newContentPane = new DocumentContent();
                   newContentPane.Content = item;
                   var itemView = (item as IViewBase);
                   if (itemView != null)
                       newContentPane.Title = itemView.Title;
                   //When contentPane is closed remove the associated region
                   newContentPane.Closed += (contentPaneSender, args) =>
                   {
                       region.Remove(item);
                       newContentPane.Content = null;
                   };

                   document.Items.Add(newContentPane);

                   if (!resizingPanel.Children.Contains(document))
                       resizingPanel.Children.Add(document);

                   regionTarget.Content = resizingPanel;

                   newContentPane.Activate();
                   region.Activate(item);
               }
           }
       }
       else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
       {

       }
   }

   private DocumentPane GetDocumentPane(UIElementCollection collection)
   {
       foreach (object item in collection)
       {
           var documentPanel = item as DocumentPane;
           if (documentPanel != null)
               return documentPanel;
       }
       return new DocumentPane();
   }

   private ResizingPanel GetResizingPanel(object content)
   {
       var resizingPanel = content as ResizingPanel;
       if (resizingPanel != null)
           return resizingPanel;
       return new ResizingPanel();
   }    
   }
   ```

And your in your XAML you could implement it like this:

```
<avalon:DockingManager prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion">
</avalon:DockingManager>
```

How it works?
Simple, first at all you have to keep in mind that [*Region adapters are responsible for creating a region and associating it with the control. This allows you to use the IRegion interface to manage the UI control contents in a consistent way.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921098%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx#sec15)

And a [*DockingManager is the core control in AvalonDock. It arranges contained panes, handles fly out panes and floating windows.*](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GettingStarted&referringTitle=Documentation)

So, following this example you could have implemented a custom region adapter for avalon, I worked with this implementation in a project getting awesome results.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I use CaliburnMicro instead of Prism. I'll have a look at Sofa, to check if I can manage to find a solution