# C# Property Grid Auto Hide

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using `PropertyGrid` class to show properties of shapes in my canvas it works fine, but I am stuck at a place that I want it to auto hide the same way that we auto hide the property window - Solution Explorer - in Visual Studio.

Is there any property / event that can achieve this?

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344205/recommendations-on-a-wpf-docking-library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your property grid in dock panel, look at http://avalondock.codeplex.com/