# How to create a bottom panel without auto-hide using AvalonDock 2.0?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

**I'm using AvalonDock 2.0**

I feel that it's supposed to be pretty basic but the documentation doesn't say a thing and I've played around for 2 hours to try and figure it out. So, I'm sorry if this is too simple.

I want exactly what the title says. The documentation mentions how to make a bottom side panel but only an auto-hidden one, which is not what I want.

I tried to toggle it's autohide in code-behind but the height wasn't affected so every single time the application starts the user has to drag it up to see the panel's content.

Comment: It would be convenient if you could post any example you tried.

Answer (score 4):

A bit hacky but this worked for me:

```
    <xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockingManager" Grid.Row="1" DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}" Loaded="DockingManager_OnLoaded">
        <xcad:LayoutRoot>
            <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane></xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="Auto" SelectedContentIndex="0">
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Right">
                        <Label>Right</Label>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            <xcad:LayoutRoot.BottomSide>
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable x:Name="OutputAnchorable" Title="Output">
                            <Label>Bottom</Label>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorGroup>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorSide>
            </xcad:LayoutRoot.BottomSide>
        </xcad:LayoutRoot>
    </xcad:DockingManager>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
    private void DockingManager_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OutputAnchorable.ToggleAutoHide();

        // You might want to do this to get a reasonable height
        var root = (LayoutAnchorablePane)OutputAnchorable.Parent;
        root.DockHeight = new GridLength(100);
    }
```

Comment: Also works in AvalonDock 3.5 without the code behind part https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/blob/master/source/TestApp/MainWindow.xaml

Comment: @user8276908 Apparently it doesn't, at least I was not able to get it to work. The sample markup you linked still automatically hides the `LayoutAnchorable` for me.

Comment: @Carsten Thats really strange, there are sample [apps](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/wiki/WPF-VS-2013-Dark-Light-Demo-Client) in that repository where you can load and save layouts including hidden ´LayoutAnchorables´. But maybe I go the requirements wrong and you actually need an (interactive solution](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock/issues/145), if yes, I am the maintainer, maybe we should do a command binding to make it easy (as suggested in the issue). It goes faster if someone submits a working PR :-)

Comment: I see now this is not about Hidden panels so the referenced apps link shold give you a working example for it (period). I just cannot edit my comment anymore so forget about the 2nd part of my comment :-(

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this

```
<xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  >   


</xcad:LayoutPanel>
</xcad:LayoutPanel>
```

The second layout will create all the mix panels, the first will create the top or bottom in vertical way