# Creating a subform within a main form

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, datarepeater, subforms

I'm trying to mimic an access form where I have a subform embedded within a main form.  The subform will be populated by a query based on the main form id.  When the record changes the subform data will change.  Is this possible to do in c#?

I tried looking for a data repeater but the only one I found was a VisualBasic.PowerPacks data repeater.

This is a very important app and the lead wants it to look and act just like the access app.  I know that doesn't make sense but that is what he wants.

Any help pointing me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: When you say sub form in the main form, do you mean Multiple Document Interface? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_document_interface

Comment: I don't think MDI is what you are looking for. You can use the Visual Studio provided DataSource/form builder tools to have a form with details from a master record and a "subform" DatagridView that displays the detail records.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e.aspx). With WinForm .Net framework provides MDI forms. You should see: How to: [Create MDI Child Forms - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7aw8zc76.aspx).

You may also see: [Introduction to MDI Forms with C# - Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3553/Introduction-to-MDI-Forms-with-C)

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  Sorry I forgot to mention it is a winforms application.  I'm going to go through the links and figure it all out.  Thank you

Comment: I was able to create a parent/child form using the links that were posted.  How can I show data being repeated in the subform like in access?

Comment: Would using VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeater work in a "C#" app? Will I run into issues down the road?  Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: @JerryWarra, don't create a C# app, you can create MDI forms in VB.Net as well. Its from the framework.

Comment: Habib thank you for your reply.  I can't use VB.net.  I'm using C# but i'm going to use the VisualBasic.PowerPacks.DataRepeater.  I'm just trying to figure out how to get the combobox populated and then databind a value to it.

Answer (score 2):

The old way was called MDI (Multiple document interface). You can still use this but with an external library (like [WPFMDI](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/)).

The newer method is to use dockable windows, but you have to program them manually.
See: [Recommendations on a WPF Docking Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344205/recommendations-on-a-wpf-docking-library)

Comment: Michel, with dockable windows how can I create a datarepeater to mimic how it is in access?

Comment: I don't know about data repeaters. I edited my answer for a link how to use dockable windows.