# AvalonDock Now Loses Alt Key Adornments

Tags: wpf, mvvm, avalondock, alt-key

I've been using AvalonDock (2.0) for some time now, being key for managing documents in an IDE.  In the last month or so, I've noticed that <kbd>Alt</kbd> key adornments are no longer showing up for controls within AvalonDock, though the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key commands are executing as expected.  See the image below where the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key adornments are showing up in the menu, but not for the buttons inside AvalonDock:

[image: No Alt Keys]

What is particularly interesting about this issue, that it appears to be triggered by an environmental setting or condition.

As demonstrated in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D-S_PGJoTkc) (at 2:07), the alt key adornments are working for a control within AvalonDock. But, if I now use the very same executable I used in that video, the alt key adornments do not work.

I'm currently using build 2.0.1746, but I also tried build 2.0.2000 (with the Xceed namespace) and found the same issue.  I also tried the version packaged with the [Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.com/), and found that the issue persists.

I also built a very simple test application which loads a couple of documents of type `Item`, where `Item` is a simple class with a `Name` property:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:avalonDock="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock"
        xmlns:avalonDockLayout="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Layout;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock"
        xmlns:avalonDockControls="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.Controls;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Content="Item:" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <Button Content="_ClickMe" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <avalonDock:DockingManager Grid.Row="0"  DocumentsSource="{Binding}">
            <avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
                <avalonDockLayout:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <avalonDockLayout:LayoutDocumentPane/>
                </avalonDockLayout:LayoutPanel>
            </avalonDockLayout:LayoutRoot>
        </avalonDock:DockingManager>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="_Test" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Even with this simple application, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key adornments show up for the `Test` button outside of AvalonDock, but not for the `ClickMe` buttons for the controls within AvalonDock.

I also posted the issue [here](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/workitem/16479) on the AvalonDock codeplex site, but there appears to be very little response activity.  I also posted the issue [here](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/20471) on the Extended Toolkit codeplex site.

Any ideas on how to correct or workaround this issue?

Comment: If you have an Xceed subscription, it might be worth contacting their support people. You might also want to try their own forum: http://xceed.com/CS/forums/86/ShowForum.aspx

Comment: Thanks Richard, I will post on that forum as well, and maybe get a subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though this will be fixed with the next version of AvalonDock.

In the meantime, the following Blend behavior is a workaround:

```
public class FixKeyboardCuesBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    private static readonly DependencyProperty ShowKeyboardCuesProperty;

    static FixKeyboardCuesBehavior()
    {
        Type keyboardNavigation = typeof(KeyboardNavigation);
        var field = keyboardNavigation.GetField("ShowKeyboardCuesProperty", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

        Debug.Assert(field != null, "field != null");

        ShowKeyboardCuesProperty = (DependencyProperty)field.GetValue(null);
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        Window rootWindow = Window.GetWindow(this.AssociatedObject);
        if (rootWindow == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
            this.AssociatedObject,
            ShowKeyboardCuesProperty,
            new Binding("(KeyboardNavigation.ShowKeyboardCues)") { Source = rootWindow });
    }
}
```

Use this from XAML by adding the following to the root element of your `DataTemplate` for the AvalonDock `LayoutItemTemplate`:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <my:FixKeyboardCuesBehavior />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

This workaround uses internal implementation details of WPF to re-introduce the <kbd>Alt</kbd> behaviour below the broken AvalonDock logical tree.  So, I'll be looking forward to being able to zap it from my code when AD itself is fixed!

Comment: Thanks Olly, I'm going with your workaround in the meantime as well.  Should be fixed in Xceed Wpf Toolkit 2.3.