# Interactions with AvalonEdit window in an AvalonDock

Tags: avalondock, avalonedit

In my application we use `AvalonDock` for a docking manager, and have a variety of different windows. One of those contains an `AvalonEdit` editor. We recently noticed one specific interaction issue which I figured out to be caused by the `AvalonDock`.

When trying to block select code, you can use a bunch of different methods: `Alt + click and drag`, `Alt + Shift + click and drag`, `Alt + Shift + arrow keys`, and so on. One specific method, Alt + click and drag doesn't work. Specifically it does select, but typing doesn't work until you press either escape or space once. With `Alt + Shift + click and drag` it works fine.

I tested the `AvalonEdit` sample project as well as making my own simple example and it worked fine. When I put a test `AvalonEdit` window in a `Window` control instead of within a `UserControl` that's docked in my docking manager, it works fine. So something is going on with the interaction between having the `AvalonEdit` window within a `AvalonDock` vs. having it within some other window. Has anyone worked with these two controls together before? I know they're both used in `SharpDevelop` so I'd expect that they should work well together.

I found another issue which also has an alt-related issue with `AvalonDock` but it doesn't seem to be exactly what I'm seeing: [AvalonDock Now Loses Alt Key Adornments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036898/avalondock-now-loses-alt-key-adornments). Also they claim that issue has been fixed, and I can't even test the solution in the answer as I don't have/use Blend. Looking at that bug makes me think it's more an issue with `AvalonDock` though and not `AvalonEdit`

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out that `AvalonDock` wasn't the culprit directly. The real issue was a WPF Ribbon control which was stealing the focus when you pressed Alt. Killing hotkeys on the Ribbon fixed the editor interactions.